# pg_basebackup fails with message: could not create directory

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a hot standby server using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 and Red Hat 6.5 
I receive the folowing error when running pg_basebackup:

```
$ pg_basebackup -h 172.28.250.10 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data -U replicador -v -P
pg_basebackup: could not create directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/osm_indices":
 File exists
```

/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data exists and is empty when I launch the tool and when it fails there is data at /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/osm_indices. The DB has 5 tablespaces and 4 are completely copied.
Both servers are running the same O.S. and DB server version.
I've tried the same with 2 different masters and 3 slaves with the same result, but not always is the same tablespaces that fails to copy.

Thanks,
     Luis.

Comment: Have you created tablespaces within the main data directory, by any chance?

Comment: Yes. All my tablespaces are within /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/  Is this a problem??

Comment: Yeah, I think we need to improve the documentation about that. Tablespaces are not supposed to be inside the data directory, and most of the tools get quite confused if they are.

Comment: I've move my tablespaces and now it works!!  Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you might have tablespaces inside the data directory.

You should not do that. Tablespaces are meant to be separate paths, and some of the tools assume that they will be.

Move the tablespaces outside the datadir and `pg_basebackup` should behave, so long as you have corresponding paths on the destination server.

Comment: With the new pg_basebackup in 9.4 onwards I can relocate tablespaces to a new location on replica.